# How does string.replaceAll() work?

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I am making a program that replaces a certain part of the string.

```
String x = "hello";
x=x.replaceAll("e","\\\\s");
System.out.println(x);
```

output: **h\sllo**

but for

```
System.out.println("\\s");
```

output: **\s**

why do we need extra escape characters in the first case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You need `\\` for a single `\` character in regex
- But Java string also interprets backslash therefore you need to escape each `\` for String hence you need 2+2=4 backslashes to match a single `\` (2 for String and 2 for regex engine)
- Also note that 2nd argument to `String#replaceAll` method is also interpreted by regex engine due to potential presence of back-references and that is the reason same regex rules apply for replacement string also.
- Your regex is using replacement string of a literal `\` followed by a literal `s`

Comment: -1.  Read the question more carefully.  It's not the regex he's talking about, it's the replacement string.

Comment: @AlanMoore: Sorry I wrote `matching` instead of `replacing` (fixed now) but I did read the question well before answering.

Comment: What I meant is that it's the *second argument* you're talking about.  That's not a regex, but it requires you escape backslashes for another reason.

Comment: Yes 2nd argument is also interpreted by regex engine due to potential presence of back-references and that is same regex rules apply for replacement string. (May be I should clearly add this line in my answer).

Comment: It has nothing to do with the regex engine, is what I'm saying.    The only other character that has special meaning in the replacement string is the dollar sign, and its specialness has no connection to its usage in a regex.  Maybe I'm just having a flareup of [SWOTI Syndrome](https://xkcd.com/386/), but I think it's important to understand that the code that processes the replacement string is completely independent of the routines that parse the regex string.